# SlideOut control on click event in CSS or Angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, angular

I want to implement a slideout and it should slideout on click event. I searched and I am able to implement the slideout on hover, but i wanted to have it on click event. also the slideout should close/collapse on the click event on the button placed inside i.e. in the example it should close only on the click event of the close button.

I am working on a angular2 application and the examples which i am getting in internet is on Jquery. but I wanted to get it implemented in CSS or in angular2

Please find the implementation 
[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/snkrishnan1/efhfos7L/3/)

Any ideas how to implement?

Comment: it's possible. Do you have any code where you are working on now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heaps of way to do this, but based on your code the easies is :

You just need to add a class on click

```
[class.slideItOut]="slideItOut" (click)="slideItOut=true"
```

Here :

```
<div id="slideout" [class.slideItOut]="slideItOut" (click)="slideItOut=true">
    <img src="http://img.usabilitypost.com.s3.amazonaws.com/1104/css_slideout/feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
    <div id="slideout_inner">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Close"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And obviously, if you want it to toggle :

```
[class.slideItOut]="slideItOut" (click)="slideItOut=!slideItOut"
```

And then , update your css to :

```
#slideout.slideItOut {
    right: 250px;
}
#slideout.slideItOut #slideout_inner {
    right: 0;
}
```

Also, don't forget to define **slideItOut** variable inside it's class :

```
export class MySliderComponent {

   private slideItOut = false;
...
```